# CreateProcess I can't start a process

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am using CreateProcess, but I can't start a process I am using the following code but I am getting the error "Invalid access to memory location" but I don't know why.
Is there any problem with my code?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//#include "common.h"

int main(void)
{

    DWORD creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS;
    STARTUPINFO startupinfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_information;
    char *path_to_exe = "D:\\dbg\\calc.exe";


    startupinfo.dwFlags     =   0x1;
    startupinfo.wShowWindow =   0x0;


    startupinfo.cb  =   sizeof(startupinfo);

    if(CreateProcess(   path_to_exe,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        creation_flags,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        &startupinfo,
                        &process_information)){
        printf("We have successfully launched the process!\n");
        printf("[*] PID: %d\n", process_information.dwProcessId);
    }
    else
        printf("[*] Error: %d.\n", GetLastError());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only filled in 3 fields of the `startupinfo` Structure.
The remaining fields are filled with garbage, and some of that garbage is likely leading to bad problems.

You should fully initialize the structure, explicitly putting NULL, 0 and other "empty" values where you don't want to specify anything.

Comment: [The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) says that "The *lpCommandLine* parameter can be NULL. In that case, the function uses the string pointed to by *lpApplicationName* as the command line", so that shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The simplest way to initialize it to all zeros is: STARTUPINFO startupinfo = {0};

Comment: @Ferruccio:  That will initialize it all to zero.  But that may not necessarily be what is needed in many cases. Consider a hypothetical field "int timeout; // number of seconds before aborting the process.  Set to -1 to wait forever"   Setting it to zero would cause it to fail immediately.  -1 is what is needed there.   Blanket setting everything to zero is risky.

Comment: @abelenky: you're right, but initializing it to all zeros puts it in a known state rather than having whatever random values happened to be on the stack. You would then set any desired fields as necessary.

Comment: @abelenky: The Win32 API almost always uses 0 as the default value, and the only exceptions I can name are deprecated API's dating back to Win16. Of course, not all members have default values, and in particular the first `cb` (count of bytes) member has to be set always. That's why I usually write `STARTUPINFO startupinfo = {sizeof(startupinfo};`

Answer (score 1):

Try zeroing the startup info structure. Some of it's members (e.g. lpTitle) are used even if you don't set an explicit flag.

Also beware that CreateProcess may temporarily write to the application name string, so you may want to avoid passing a read-only string literal. This only happens with the unicode version of the function though, at least on recent versions of Windows.